Show that $|\det (a_1, \ldots, a_k, b_1, \ldots, b_{n-k})|=\left|\det\left(\left\langle a_i, d_j\right\rangle \right)\right|$
Let $U$, $L$ be subspaces such that $U \oplus L= \mathbb{R}^n$, and choose orthonormal bases $a_1,\dots,a_k$ for $U$, $b_1,\dots,b_{n-k}$ for $L$, and $d_1,\dots, d_{k}$ for $L^\bot$. I want to show that
$$\left|\operatorname{det}\begin{bmatrix}
\mid &  & \mid & \mid & & \mid \\
a_1 & \dots & a_k  &b_1  & \dots & b_{n-k}  \\
\mid &  & \mid & \mid & & \mid
\end{bmatrix} \right|=\left|\operatorname{det}\left(\left\langle a_i, d_j\right\rangle_{i, j=1}^k\right)\right|.$$
My only idea was that $ \left\langle a_i, d_j\right\rangle_{i, j=1}^k= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mid & \mid & & \mid \\
a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_k \\
\mid & \mid & & \mid
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
\mid & \mid &  & \mid \\
d_1 & d_2 & \dots & d_k \\
\mid & \mid &  & \mid
\end{bmatrix}$,
but I don't know how this might help me. What would be the step in the right direction to prove this?

One approach is as follows.
Let $A$ denote the matrix whose columns are $a_1,\dots,a_k$, $B$ the matrix whose columns are $b_1,\dots,b_{n-k}$, and $D$ the matrix whose columns are $d_1,\dots,d_k$. Notably, the matrix $[D\ \ B]$ is orthogonal, so it follows that
$$
|\det [D\ \ B]^T[A\ \ B]| = |\det[D\ \ B]| \cdot |\det[A\ \ B]| = |\det[A\ \ B]|.
$$
On the other hand, we can use block-matrix multiplication compute
$$
[D\ \ B]^T[A\ \ B] = 
\pmatrix{
D^TA & D^TB\\
B^TA & B^TB
} = \pmatrix{
D^TA & 0\\
B^TB & I_{n-k}\\}.
$$
This is a block-upper-triangular matrix with square blocks along the diagonal. As such, its determinant is equal to
$$
\det \pmatrix{
D^TA & 0\\
B^TB & I_{n-k}\\} = \det(D^TA)\det(I_{n-k}) = \det(D^TA),
$$
which is equal to the desired result.

Thank you! You said “one approach”, do you know of others as well? If so, could you give me an idea of what they are?

@ImHackingXD I didn't have any particular alternative in mind when I said that. That said, some other approaches that might be fruitful are considering the matrix $[A\ \ B]^T[A\ \ B]$ and considering the QR factorization (or equivalently the Gram Schmidt orthonormalization of the columns) of $[B\ \ A]$. I think the approach I presented is about as clean as a proof as you can get, though
